# Erro ao inserir documentos no MongoDB

Tags: c#, api, mongodb, postman

Fiz esses inserts pelo shell do mongo:

```
db.Operators.insert([{ 
    Name:'Paulo de Tarso',
    Version:1
}, { 
    Name:'José de Arimatéia',
    Version:1
}, { 
    Name:'Catarina Silva', 
    Version:3
}])
```

Essa é minha entity na API

```
public class Operator : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public int Version { get; protected set; }

    public Operator(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Tenho os seguinte cenários:

Ao dar um Get pelo Postman, pego esse erro:

> Internal Server Error

Esse erro acontece, porque a minha classe de *request* vem vazia

Minha controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet(Name ="GetAllOperators")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetOperators()
{
    List<OperatorResult> operatorResults = await operatorsQueries.GetOperator();
    List<OperatorDetailsModel> operatorDetailsModels = new List<OperatorDetailsModel>();
    operatorResults.ForEach(x => operatorDetailsModels.Add(new OperatorDetailsModel(x.OperatorId, x.Name)));

    var defaultReturn = new DefaultReturn(operatorResults, false, string.Empty);

    return new ObjectResult(defaultReturn);
}
```

Meu GetOperator da classe operatorsQueries

```
public async Task<List<OperatorResult>> GetOperator()
{
    List<Operator> operators = await context.Operators.Find(x => true).ToListAsync();
    List<OperatorResult> operatorResults = resultConverter.Map<List<OperatorResult>>(operators);
    return operatorResults;
}
```

A lambda pega aqui

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    DomainException domainException = context.Exception as DomainException;
    if (domainException != null)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(domainException.BusinessMessage);
        var defaultReturn = new DefaultReturn(new { }, true, domainException.BusinessMessage);
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(defaultReturn);
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }
}
```

Aqui dá o erro, pois o meu `domainException` está vindo **`NULL`** e não deveria.

No outro cenário é quando eu insiro pelo **Postman** o documento. Nesse caso, não tenho esse erro, mas o campo Version vem (0) por ser um int.

Só não testei com ferramentas GUI para o Mongo, como **Robo 3T**, por exemplo.

Comment: Creio que esse problema acontece, quando eu insiro na "mão" o documento. A minha Api não deve reconhecer, pois se eu insiro pelo Postman, esse erro não acontece.

Comment: Esta nulo porque tem `context.Exception as DomainException`. Quem te garante que as exceções geradas serão sempre do tipo **`DomainException`**? Você precisa ver a exceção a original e seu tratamento de exceções está gerando outra exceção...

Comment: Outra coisa, mas não relacionado com o problema, qual o objetivo de usar **`protected set`**?

Comment: Não sei te explicar, @LINQ, teria que conversar com os caras da API, mas eles não ficam no meu andar, pelo menos dessa API. Mas o problema foi resolvido, pois eles removeram o campo Version, não será mais necessário e dou por encerrado o post

Comment: Fecha a pergunta então, se possível. Porque não tá fazendo sentido nenhum e não tem como ajudar alguém no futuro, então...